# Is it allowed to have null foreign key in sqlite when PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

according to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_basics) null foreign keys are allowed unless and until we are adding the appropriate "NOT NULL" constraint to the schema.

but I am seeing the some different behavior,

```
sqlite> PRAGMA Foreign_keys;
1
sqlite> create table proc (
sqlite>   pid integer,
sqlite>   name text,
sqlite>   ppid integer,
sqlite>   foreign key (ppid) references proc (id)
sqlite> );
sqlite> .schema proc
CREATE TABLE proc (
  pid integer,
  name text,
  ppid integer,
  foreign key (ppid) references proc (id)
);

sqlite> insert into proc (pid, name, ppid)
sqlite> values (0, "init", null);
Error: foreign key mismatch

sqlite> PRAGMA Foreign_keys=OFF;
sqlite> PRAGMA Foreign_keys;
0

sqlite> insert into proc (pid, name, ppid)
sqlite> values (0, "init", null);
sqlite> select * from proc;
0|init|
```

how can I allow null foreign key in sqlite when PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON? or it is not possible at all?

Comment: here `foreign key (ppid) references proc (id)` was a typo, that should be `foreign key (ppid) references proc (pid)`, and as suggested by @CL. i made `pid` a `PRIMARY KEY`. This is working at sqlite prompt but not in android-sqlite..

android is throwing exception `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: foreign key constraint failed (code 19)`

Comment: Hi Rupesh, I am getting foreign key as nulls.Can you please look at it.These are my 2 tables   Table 1 -   final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE = "create table if not exists scannerValuess (id integer,partName text null,cost text null,foreign key(id) references scannerUserValuess(userid))";    Table 2 -    final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_USER = "create table if not exists scannerUserValuess (userid integer primary key autoincrement,name text not null,mobile text not null,address text not null,date text not null)";    Please help me ASAP.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The ID column is named `pid`, not `id`.
2. The parent key column must have a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

Comment: `id` was a typo.. and yes when I made pid a PRIMARY KEY, it worked like charm.. Thanks.

Comment: I was using [ContentValues](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html) to insert record in table, for inserting a value `null` one should use API [putNull()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#putNull(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Here does not work. I have a primary key autoincrement on a parent table. The insert into the child table with FK=null does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a [foreign key clause](http://www.sqlite.org/syntax/foreign-key-clause.html) by changing your table create statement to:

```
CREATE TABLE proc (pid integer, name text, ppid integer, foreign key (ppid) references 
proc (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL);
```